# Execlp with read

Tags: c, fork, exec

I wanna implement a program that reads from stdin using a shell command and then I have to store the input and do other things with it.

```
        int a[2];
        if(pipe(a)==-1){
                err(1, "error while creating a pipe");
        }

        int fd=fork();
        if(fd<0){
                err(1, "error while forking");
        }

        if(fd==0){
                close(a[0]);
                dup2(a[1], 1);
                execlp("read", "read", NULL);
        }

        close(a[1]);
        dup2(a[0], 0);
```

It does not take an input, how I can fix it?

Comment: Most likely, `read` objects to not being told which variable to read into.  It might read the input, but there is no way for you to find out what it read.  You need to rethink what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can you suggest other ways to do it? I wanna use exec to read from stdin

Comment: What do you want to do with what is read from standard input?  Ignore it?  Get it into the program that forks?  Why can't you just call `read()` from within your program?  Why do you need to fork at all?  This is probably an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You should outline your objective in higher-level terms.  Normally, `read` is a shell built-in.  POSIX requires a standalone utility — on macOS, it's `/usr/bin/read`.  It will read one line of input and then stop, making the data vanish.

Answer (score 1):

`read` is a shell built-in.  It can be run only as a shell command, not launched directly via any of the `exec`-family functions.  If you check, you will very likely find that your `execlp()` call is failing (returning a nonzero value), which is a twofold problem for you:

1. The failure itself means that the work you wanted done does not, in fact, get done.  But also
2. After `execlp()` returns, which it does only if it fails, the child process goes on to perform work that was intended only for the parent process.

You should always check your system calls for errors, but more so for the `exec`-family functions than for most.  Generally speaking, if `execlp` or one of its siblings fails, you want that process to perform an `_exit(1)` soon after.

The correct way to run a shell command via `execlp` is to launch a shell, specifying the command(s) to run via a `-c` argument.  That would look something like this:

```
    execlp("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "read", (char *) NULL);
```

You can use a different shell (`bash`, `zsh`, *etc*.) if you prefer.

**But also**, `read` consumes input and stores it in one or more shell variables.  It does not produce output, so I'm not sure how you expect to determine whether it read anything or not.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :) I know that read stores the input into a shell variable, but is it possible to store it in a c varible?

Comment: Note that POSIX requires a standalone utilty `read` — it's `/usr/bin/read` on macOS.   That said, Ubuntu 22.04 does not seem to provide a `read` executable.  The POSIX spell specification lists some [special built-in utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14) that do not have to be a separate executable, and `read` is not one of those.

Comment: Again, @Vanessa, `read` stores the data read into one or more *shell* variables.  Shell variables are not C variables.  They especially are not C variables in the (entirely separate) parent process.  If you want to get the data read back to the parent process then the most natural way to do that seems to be to write it to the pipe you set up.  But in that case, it's unclear what the point of the fork and shell command was, as it would be easier for the original program to just read the input directly.

Comment: Fair enough, @JonathanLeffler.  I didn't check POSIX before posting, but I did check my local SUSE installation, which does not provide a standalone `read` either.